# how to index into a parsed json array

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, reactjs

I was going the the reactjs tutorial [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html), and after completing the tutorial I started tinkering a little bit. One problem I ran into was that I couldn't figure out how to index into a certain array (at least it seems to be an array). Here is the code for when the array is gotten from the server:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
```

`componentDidMount` is part of a Reactjs class definition for a class called `CommentBox`, the json file being parsed looks something like

```
[
    {id: 1, author: "Pete Hunt", text: "This is one comment"},
    {id: 2, author: "Jordan Walke", text: "This is *another* comment"}
]
```

So now I tried to change the same `CommentBox` class's `render` method to add a line to print the first element of the data array. The render method became

```
render: function() {
        return (
          < div className = "commentBox" >
            {this.state.data[0].toString()}
            < h1 > Comments < /h1>
            < CommentList data = {this.state.data} / >
            < CommentForm onCommentSubmit = {this.handleCommentSubmit} / >
          < /div>
        );
}
```

where the line I added was `{this.state.data[0].toString()}`. This line causes an error which says that `this.state.data[0]` is undefined. How am I supposed to get at the elements of `this.state.data`? Shouldn't it just be a normal array, as if it was set by the following code?

```
this.state.data = [
    {id: 1, author: "Pete Hunt", text: "This is one comment"},
    {id: 2, author: "Jordan Walke", text: "This is *another* comment"}
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the "A" in "Ajax" stands for asynchronous; `render` is called *before* your data ever makes it back from the server. That means that the first time `render` is called, `this.state.data` could be undefined (depending on your `getInitialState` function).

A common approach is to add a sentinel value that keeps the component from rendering fully — or renders something different — until the data is available:

```js
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      loaded: false // `loaded` will be our sentinel value
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({
          data: data,
          loaded: true // make sure to set `loaded` to true
        });
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },

  render: function() {
        // if the sentinel isn't set, we're not ready
        if (!this.state.loaded) return <div>Loading...</div>;

        return (
          < div className = "commentBox" >
            {this.state.data[0].toString()}
            < h1 > Comments < /h1>
            < CommentList data = {this.state.data} / >
            < CommentForm onCommentSubmit = {this.handleCommentSubmit} / >
          < /div>
        );
  }
```

Alternatively, you could check for the value of `this.state.data` (or something else appropriate) to determine if the data is ready to be rendered or not.

Comment: This fixed it. I actually hadn't used ajax before so I didn't know how it worked.